# How to connect to a personal server on residential Internet service

Tags: ssh, localhost

OK!!! I've successfully connected from an external network on both ssh and http.  I changed a BUNCH of settings though before I got it to work, so I'm going to slowly change some of them back to see where the problem(s) really was(were).

Thanks for all the suggestions!!!

This ought to be a pretty simple answer, but I can't find it anywhere, and it's really confusing me.  I am new to Ubuntu, and am trying to configure a web server.  I have gone through tons of tutorials, and run into "host" or "localhost" very often.  For example, to execute *ssh user@localhost*, I would replace *user* with my username, and *localhost* with my internal IP address (connecting from the same local network).  That much, I can do.

I just want to make sure that all I have to do is replace *host* with my external (ISP provided) IP address to ssh from an outside network???  The thing is that I have done that, and it hasn't worked, so I want to make sure that my syntax isn't the problem.  Thanks so much for your patience and support.

---

Ok.  Everyone's saying I need to forward ports.  I did forward ports 80 and 22 through my router to my server, but it's not working.  I also contacted my ISP, and they said that they didn't know of any ISP restrictions on ports.  So, yes.  I think I set it up, but it's still not working.  Also, I completely bypassed my router, and connected my server directly to the modem, which does NOT have an internal router, and the problem was still there.  Since somebody upvoted this question, I can now post my pic :)[image]

Comment: Did you remember to forward port `22` to your Ubuntu server?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to set that up.  I was going to post a screen shot of my router config page, but apparently I need two more rep in order to get that permission...

Comment: Do you try to connect to your external IP from inside the LAN? This doesn't work usually. Try that from outside of your local network.

Comment: no, I did it from a cell phone with WiFi disabled, so that it would have to go through  cell network, and gave external IP  to a friend and had them try.  I know it doesn't work from inside, because I have that set up to go to router config...

Comment: How do you determine your external IP? How does it look like (give us 2 first numbers at least). Can you be using a wrong IP or an IP from your internal network by mistake?

Comment: I searched on google "what is my ip" and also went to whatismyip.com.  Both gave me the same result.  It is absolutely not an internal IP, though I can't confirm whether it is the correct external one or not.

Comment: You modem's config  should be telling you your external IP - can you confirm it matches?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Does your webserver or ssh work when you connect from another device on your local network? Also, do you have `iptables` on your system as this can block access from non-local addresses (or even all adresses).

Comment: Both work from other computers on the LAN.  I'm not sure about IPtables.  It's starting to look like the problem is with the modem config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From other answers and comments, I think your ip forward problem looks solved so coming back to the original question about host and localhost: yes, in this case, host is your external IP. Usually, `host` means any host (ip or hostname or url), internal or external depending on the situation and `localhost` is not any internal IP but the IP of the machine you are working on (lo interface - IP 127.0.0.1) and provided you have something like `127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost` (or only localhost as is the default) in `/etc/hosts` you can let it as `localhost` without substitution.

For example you can:

`ping localhost` and 127.0.0.1 (your machine loopback interface - lo) should answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to forward a port used by SSH (22) on your router so all traffic coming on that port from outside is redirected to your Ubuntu machine.

See this article: http://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/ or search for "forward port router".

Once you have port forwarding correctly configured, you'll be able to use your **external IP address**, or any DNS name configured to point to that IP address, to connect to your Ubuntu box from outside. The IP is the most robust way to do this. So, in your case, you need to replace (host) in (user)@(host) with your external IP address.

Also, as I said, getting proxy errors suggests that there's a proxy in the middle, which shouldn't be there. Which suggests that something is mis-configured.

Comment: Thanks, I actually already used that tutorial, and many others, to try to get port forwarding set up.  It says it is set up, but is not working.  In ssh, I get a timeout error, and through http, I get error 502 bad gateway.  bad response from proxy server or destination server...

Comment: I don't think that's the problem.  I've connected the server directly to  the modem, without a router at all, and it still didn't work.  With that setup, wouldn't  all traffic  be sent directly to the server, without any forwarding?

Comment: Is your modem an old-style "dumb" modem which is connected to the computer via something which is not a LAN cable? These days modems often act as routers, i.e. you can plug multiple devices into the modem and the devices will be able access Internet and each other - maybe you need to set up port forwarding on your _modem_? Please describe what "connected the server directly to the modem" means

Comment: My modem is  a centurylink 660.  It has a phone jack and a LAN cable.  I think I just found its config page, and it seems that it has at least a firewall... I'm going to try adjusting that.  If i need to port forward from my modem, which is only connected to my router, do I forward to my router @192.168.1.1 so that my router can forward to my server?

Comment: "connected the server directly to the modem" means that I took the LAN cable coming out of the modem (the one that typically feeds the router) and plugged it into the back of the server.

Answer (score 1):

Ok.  To answer my original, official question,  refers to  the external IP address (ISP provided), and   refers to the internal IP address.  There is no extra punctuation necessary, and you do not need to include the internal IP address when entering , as that should be setup through port forwarding.

Now, the solution to my problem was not really a solution, but several solutions.  It turns out that my configuration of my ROUTER was correct, and as determined in a previous question, we knew that my SERVER firewall was configured properly because I was able to access my home page and my server through  ssh while on the LOCAL network.  The big problem was with my MODEM; I had already set up a sort of port forwarding in my modem, but it was not configured properly to route  to my router.  Also, I had to make my modem's firewall accept WAN to LAN communication.  In addition to updating these settings, which still needed to be done, I am sorry to admit that I switched the locations of two numbers in my external IP address.

All that said,  I really appreciate everyone's participation, as your comments helped me to find the modem configuration, which ultimately lead me to the correction of my erroneous IP address, and the multiple necessary solutions to my problem, which has been plaguing me for three days now...

Answer (score 0):

http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/H/host.html

In short, it refers to the computer.  Host is usually used in the context of networking.

Comment: Yeah, I also started explaining what "host" means, but if you re-read the question you'll see that the OP actually wants to know about port forwarding :)

Comment: Well, the problem I am having is with port forwarding, yes.  In order to work towards solving that problem, however, I am looking for the proper syntax of what "host" should be replaced with.  Nobody has corrected me yet, so I'm assuming that I was correct in assuming that it is just the IP  address, and then we can determine that the problem must somehow be with port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

SSH server binds to certain network interfaces (which usually refer to network cards in a computer).

So, checkout you /etc/sshd_config for

```
Port 22
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
```

The port should be 22 and ListenAddress should be commented out.

The second step I would take is to ckeck if you can connect to your ssh server through the interface your system is conected to the router.

Post here the output of `ifconfig` iа you don't know how to do that and I'll help you.

ps
also is there any firewall enabled in your system?

Comment: well, /etc/sshd_config does not exist, however /etc/ssh/sshd_config does, and is configured as itshoudl be.

Comment: what about The second step ?

Comment: eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:d4:21:23:5d  
          inet addr:192.168.1.95  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::213:d4ff:fe21:235d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:23462 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1103 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3946492 (3.9 MB)  TX bytes:98004 (98.0 KB)

Comment: lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:320 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:320 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:25341 (25.3 KB)  TX bytes:25341 (25.3 KB)

Comment: try ssh to 192.168.1.95 right from the shell

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: ```ssh your-user@192.168.1.95```

Comment: yes, that part has always worked.

Comment: open a console (terminal) and type in ```ssh your-user@192.168.1.95``` while sustitute your-yser with actual user name

Comment: it was the ssh from the outside that wasn't.  I've got it now.  I changed a lot of settings though, recently, and am going to go back through and see if I can change some of them back.

Comment: ok, can you get telnet access to the router from your system? ```telnet 192.168.1.1``` if you router has that IP. Can you check out if youcan ssh to your system from routers telnet session?

Comment: Have you solved your problem, do you have ssh access to your system from outside of your LAN?

Comment: yes.  ssh and http work from outside.  Now I have to figure out exactly what needed to be changed, and change back any extra settings...